# Which package is better flutter_secure_storage or getx in my scenario?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am using the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage (uses Await/Async functions) to store a value and later retrieve it. Note that everytime I open the app, I will update the value. I just use this for the purpose of storing and retrieving the values while the app is open. NOT to store so that when the app is closed and then opened again, I can retrieve it.

Now I have learned about the https://pub.dev/packages/get which is promising since I can make my variables observable which seems easier to use with less coding.

Now I just want to ask for expert advice on those who know both flutter packages whether it is worth to migrate from using ***flutter_secure_storage*** to ***get***. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

hi buddy flutter_secure_storage is a package that is used if you want to store your data in encrypted form this is used when you are dealing with very sensitive data like you are creating an application for banking service so you need super security where as the getX package is a all-in-one package for state management, route management, Internationalization, API calling etc, it has lots of features and very easy to use. It can also Store your data but Not in Encrypted form it is basically an alternative to Shared_Preference package, so if you want to store data in Encrypted format then go for flutter_secure_storage and if you don't need Encrypted storage then you can use getX. I would definitely recommend to use getX not only for storage you can you also use it for state management and lots of other features.

Comment: Hi buddy, thanks for your insight. Yes, I don't need an encrypted storage in my case. I just need to pass the values of my variable around the page. I just came to know getX now and it is really powerful. Thanks again.